# When console.logging the window object inside component it gives 'undefined'. But it is accessible when using the browser console

Tags: javascript, reactjs, youtube-api

I want to get the current time from the appended video using the youtube API (https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference). And I want to use that information in another component, so that is why I am giving a property to the window object so I can access the information anywhere.

Code :

```
  import React from 'react';

    class VideoSingle extends React.Component {
      constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {}
      }

      componentDidMount() {
       // 2. This code loads the IFrame Player API code asynchronously.
       var tag = document.createElement('script');

       tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
       var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
       firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

       // 3. This function creates an <iframe> (and YouTube player)
       //    after the API code downloads.

       var YT;
       window.onYouTubeIframeAPIReady = function() {
         YT = window.YT;
         window.player = new YT.Player('videoplayer', {
           height: '390',
           width: '640',
           videoId: 'M7lc1UVf-VE',
           origin:'http://localhost:3001',
           events: {

           }

         });

       }

      }

      componentDidUpdate() {

        console.log(window.player,'logging window.player at componentDidUpdate')
      }
      render(){

        console.log(window.player,'logging window.player at render')


      return (
       //1. The <iframe> (and video player) will replace this <div> tag. 
        <div id="videoplayer"></div>

        );
      }
    };



export default VideoSingle;
```

All the places that I try to use console.log gives 'undefined' (in the example I console.logged in componentDidMount and render) :

[image]

But when I enter window.player.getCurrentTime() in the browser console I actually get a value

[image]

I want to understand how it is possible to access the window.player.getCurrentTime() anywhere in my application.

App repo : https://github.com/phelpa/YouList

Answer (score 1, accepted):

YouTube Script is most likely creating the player after you log... Try to render the entire view and then console log. In your code... Following lines do not make sense. Check YT API reference

```
YT = window.YT;
```

this makes YT undefined... May be you meant to say `window.YT = YT` ? Please double check. Good luck and keep us posted.

Comment: Yes, you were right, the YouTube script was creating the player after I was logging so that is why it was 'undefined' during code execution but it was fine when I was logging on the browser console (because the code finished to execute, so it existed).

I then realized that this is fine, because I am gonna submit the window.player.getCurrentTime() from a form. And when submitting it from a form the window.player object will exist so I am gonna have no problems.

Thank you for the insight.